Помогите разобраться с ссылками в C++
В книгах по C++ указано, что ссылка перед использованием должна быть инициализирована обьектом, на который она ссылается, в противном случае компилятор выдает ошибку:
int &link;// Ошибка`

Почему тогда, если ссылка обьявлена в качестве аргумента функции и не инициализирована обьектом, то ошибки нет?
int sum(int &a, int &b) {
    return (a + b);
}


Когда аргумент функции - это ссылка, то эта ссылка и будет как-раз всегда инициализирована каким нибудь объектом - тем объектом, который передан в качестве аргумента в точке вызова.

Вы имеете ввиду что инициализация аргументов происходит в момент вызова функции, то есть как бы в обьявлении функции отложенная инициализация аргументов(на этаже исполнения)

Но опять же это нарушает, формальное определение ссылки, в котором указано, что она всего лишь псевдоним, а раз псевдоним то вычисляется на этапе компиляции, а вызов функции и инициализация ее аргументов это уже этаж исполнения

Отнюдь. Никаких нарушений. Аргумент-ссылка - это ссылка (завуалированный указатель на данные, псевдоним) на объект объект, переданный в функцию.

Вообще, не очень понятно, что вы имеете в виду под отложенной инициализацией. По факту ЛЮБАЯ инициализация происходит в run-time: выделение памяти на стеке или в куче, заполнение этой памяти данными

Не любая инициализация происходит в рантайме, попробуйте обьявить и инициализоровать переменную вне тела функции и ее значение будет содержаться в исполнямом файле(PE, ELF), также можете проинициализовать статическую переменную функции результат будет тот же что и вне функции

Полностью с вами согласен что внутри ссылка это указатель, только вот само определение и требования к ссылкам в руководствах и справочниках C++ вводят в заблуждения, если псевдоним то на этапе компиляции компилятор заменяет псевдоним именем переменной, а если на этапе исполнения то это уже не псевдоним, так как он заранее не знает на какую область памяти будет ссылаться, то есть не знает псевдонимом какой переменной будет

Это вопрос интерпретации и оптимизации. То, что содержится в исполняемом файле - это значения констант, которые на абстрактном уровне интерпретируются как то, чем будут инициализированы данные, связанные с некоторым  именем. Инициализацией можно назвать и процесс заполнения байтами некой области памяти, и кусок кода, который описывает этот процесс заполнения. Если говорить в контексте аргументов функции, то кусок кода, который описывает их инициализацию находится в точках вызова функции.

Никакой путаницы в справочниках тут нет. Просто немного расширьте своё понятие такой абстракции, как псевдоним. Людей прекрасно обслуживают в магазине, не зная их имён. Для них это всё просто покупатели. Они даже робота андроида обслужат, если он тоже подходит под псевдоним "покупатель" (имеет соответствующий интерфейс покупателя)

Спасибо за конструктив

int* a = new int; int&b = *a; - хотелось бы знать, как вы собираетесь вычислить этот адрес во время компиляции...

Объявления и инициализация обязательно объеденены только для локальных переменных.

В вашем примере, динамическое выделение памяти во время исполнения, так что во время компиляции узнать адрес на который ссылается указатель а невозможно

Но так как ваша ссылка ссылается на значение через указатель, то вполне логично что компилятор запишет адрес указателя, а потом разыменует адрес хранящийся в нем для перехода к значению на которое он указывает

В комментариях уже много сказали, но стоит обобщить.
Вообще, то что вы спрашиваете немного разные вещи.

Это alias(псевдоним) и тут вполне логично, что он не может не быть определен, тут . никакой путаницы нету.
Это передача аргумента в функцию(по значению, по ссылке, по указателю). Другими словами это не псевдоним как было раньше, а говорит компилятору, что не нужно делать копию аргумента передаваемого в функцию, а возьми просто это по адресу в памяти.
Затем, когда вы вызываете функцию и происходит инициализация и можно сказать создание псевдонима которая указывает на это место в памяти.

